# Android AudioManager not working as expected on Chrome OS

Tags: android, google-chrome-os, androidappsonchromeos

When running my Android App on Chromebook, all my audio changes via AudioManager to not actually take effect in the behavior of the app.

When running:

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress / MAX_MULTIPIER, 0);
```

or

```
audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

(Audio Manager from getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); )

The values returned or the intended actions do not reflect the audio coming from the app. It does not matter what STREAM I'm in either, I've tried SYSTEM as well. isVolumeFixed() also returns false.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It may be a limitation of the Android-on-Chrome OS environment. You might consider creating a sample project that reproduces the error, then file an issue: `http://tiny .cc/AndroidforChrome` (sorry, but this is the URL that I was given by Google, and it expands into something far too long for a comment here on SO, and SO does not accept URL shorteners for links, so you need to remove the space yourself...)

Comment: @CommonWare is this the only way to get help in debugging android apps on Chrome OS? Is there no other developer forum or place to ask questions about this? I expected more people to be talking about the environment.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/index.html#learning-materials), you can "Post a question on the [Android developer community](https://plus.sandbox.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers) with hashtag #AndroidAppsOnChromeOS" (here, referring to Google+). I am not much of a G+ person, so I have no idea what sort of assistance you get there.

Comment: If you get an answer on Google+, please post the answer here. I am trying to do the same thing as you and would like to know the answer.

Comment: An issue for this problem has been submitted on the chromium website here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=761928